# How to return a component/component-tag dynamically in vue/nuxt?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am trying to convert a next.js app(https://medium.com/strapi/how-to-create-pages-on-the-fly-with-dynamic-zone-8eebe64a2e1) to a nuxt.js app. In this app I can fetch data from an API and the next.js app uses the APIs data to generate new pages with its corresponding content. Works well in Next.js.

The data/content from the API consists of Seo data for the page, some static values and very important of blocks. These blocks have an attribute called **__component** where the components name is saved and also have the components data like images, text, etc. So I only have to deal with next.js when adding new components.

In next.js I used the catch-all-route **./pages/[[...slug]]**.js to catch any slug an user may enter. Then the API is fired with the slug from the context.query and I get back the pages data if it exists. Now the APIs json data only needs to be passed to the blockmanager component.

```
const Universals = ({blocks}) => {
return <div><BlockManager blocks={blocks}></BlockManager></div>;
};
```

Here the blockmanager gets the json list of blocks, from which to parse the components.

```
import Hero from '../../blocks/Hero';
import Pricing from '../../blocks/Pricing';

const getBlockComponent = ({__component, ...rest}, index) => {
    let Block;

    switch (__component) {
        case 'blocks.hero':
            Block = Hero;
            break;
        case "blocks.prices":
            Block = Pricing;
            break;
    }

    return Block ? <Block key={`index-${index}`} {...rest}/> : null;
};

const BlockManager = ({  blocks  }) => {
    return <div> {blocks.map(getBlockComponent)} </div>;
};

BlockManager.defaultProps = {
    blocks: [],
};

export default BlockManager;
```

How can I replicate this line now in nuxt js?

```
return Block ? <Block key={`index-${index}`} {...rest}/> : null;
```

How to return a component/component-tag dynamically in vue/nuxt ?
Is there maybe another solution to automatically insert the wanted component?
Maybe someones knows ho to convert the blockmanagers logic to vue/nuxt logic entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I got it. No strange stuff actually. I thought about it too complicated. Wanted all dynamically created but no need as I saw later ...

```
<template v-if="blocks">
    <div id="example-1">
        <div v-for="({__component, ...rest}=block, i) in blocks" :key="i">
            <Hero :data="rest" v-if="__component === 'blocks.hero'"/>
            <Pricing :data="rest" v-if="__component === 'blocks.pricing'"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    import Hero from '../../blocks/Hero/Hero.vue';
    import Pricing from '../../blocks/Pricing/Pricing.vue';

    export default {

        components: {
            Hero, Pricing
        },
        props: {
            blocks: Array
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `is` attribute. You can read about it [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html).

Your template would look like:

```html
<component
  :is="__component"
  key={`index-${index}`}
/>
```

Comment: Could you maybe also help me with the returning part of the component? In next it was the map function, I tried to replicate but still struggle to get the hang of it

Comment: I haven't worked in React/Next, but i think you're used to JSX. Where you use Javascript to return HTML. That's not how it's usually is done in Vue. You probably want to create a `<div>` element and iterate through your blocks using `v-for`. I don't understand your question well enough to give you a specific answer on how you should do it, but consider reading [Vue's template syntax documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html).